# Why this query doesn't work (problem with EXISTS)

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, exists

I'm struggling with such query (generated by sqlalchemy. I've renamed it for clarity)

```
SELECT table.x + :dx AS cx, table.y + :dy AS cy 
FROM table
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table AS table_1
                   WHERE table_1.x = cx AND table_1.y = cy))
  AND     (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2
                   WHERE table2.table_id = table.id))
```

For dx, dy = 1, 1 and tables:

```
 Table:
  id | x | y
 ----+---+---
   1 | 0 | 0

 Table2:
  id | table_id
 ----+----------
  1  | 1
```

It should return:

```
  cx | cy
 ----+----
   1 |  1
```

However the second condition seems to return false.

**EDIT:** It seems to be a problem with transaction flushing in SQLAlchemy. I thought that in case of executing query (non-ORM mapped) it will automatically flush. However it seems that it is not flushed in such case or flushed in incorrect order. In any case adding additional `model.DBSession.flush()` seems to fixed the problem.

Comment: Should it not return `1 | 1` ?

Comment: I think line 1 should be `SELECT table.x + :dx AS cx, table.y + :dy AS cy`

Comment: I tested with your table-structure and values and the query returns `1 | 1`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Adam Bernier: It seems that you missed query caching on part of SQLAlchemy. See **edit**.

Comment: Yep I definitely missed that. Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in **edit** the problem was in flushing.